# how to set two template dirctory?

Tags: django

I have created a `middleware.py` file:

```
from django.conf import settings 

class MobileMiddleware(object):
     MOBI_REG = re.compile(
                            '(iphone|windows ce|mobile|phone|symbian|mini|pda|ipod|mobi|blackberry|playbook|vodafone|kindle)',
                                re.IGNORECASE) 
    def process_request(self, request):
        try:
            if 'HTTP_USER_AGENT' in request.META:
                userAgent = request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT')
                matches = self.MOBI_REG.search(userAgent)
                if matches:
                    settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS = settings.MOBILE_TEMPLATE_DIRS
                else:
                    settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS = settings.DESKTOP_TEMPLATE_DIRS
        except:
            settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS = settings.DESKTOP_TEMPLATE_DIRS
```

But sometime mobile version is opened in desktop version or viceversa. What cause this issue?

Comment: are you sure you are matching the right platforms? try adding print statment to your matches and the useragent headers and see if you are correctly catching them.

Comment: But when i refresh the page then it is working fine.